# Why can't load inner class? ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

Why does the following code cause `ClassNotFoundException`?

```
public class App02 {

    public static class A {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            System.out.println("A.class.getCanonicalName() = " + A.class.getCanonicalName());
            Class c = Class.forName("tests.App02.A"); //error on this line
            System.out.println(c.getName());
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A.class.getCanonicalName() = tests.App02.A
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tests.App02.A
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at tests.App02.main(App02.java:15)
```

Comment: What should `Class.forName` return if you had a package `tests.App02` with a class `A` in it?

Comment: What should it return if I had names with `$` symbol? :)

Comment: It's actually possible to call a class `$` in Java!? Why, oh the humanity!

Comment: Yes it is possible :) For example `Jsoup` did this to emulate `JQuery` :)

Comment: And if you do this `class A$ {class B {}}; class A {class $B {}}` it says "duplicate class"...

Comment: Cool, we hacked them! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `Class c = Class.forName("tests.App02$A")`.  It's not a top-level class, so use $ to locate it.

Comment: Or more exactly, App02 isn't a package, so you can't use `.` to descend into the next level.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `$` to access the *nested class*:

```
Class c = Class.forName("tests.App02$A");
```

When you compile your class, you will notice that the nested class is named as: `App02$A.class`, under package `tests`. It would make more sense then.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Didn't knew that :)

Comment: The terminology is notoriously confusing. The high point is that everybody assumes *inner* means "nested class requiring an enclosing instance", but even that isn't true: an inner class may be declared in a static context. `class Toplevel { static Object x = new Object() {}; }`

Comment: Umm. Anonymous inner class. That's where it starts to confuse more. On first look one might expect that instance to have the enclosing instance associated with it. Basically, that depends whether the reference is `static` or not. But whenever I feel confused, I stop there and look out for bytecode. That answers it :)

Comment: All anon classes are inner, and *inner* is about the restriction that it can't contain static members. Yes, if the anon class finds itself in a static context, then clearly there can't be any enclosing instance available.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using a **canonical name**, but you should use **name** (`A.class.getName()`).

In your case you should use `Class c = Class.forName("tests.App02$A");`

Answer (score 2):

There is a helpful util in commons-lang which support these classes:

```java
org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.get("tests.App02.A")
```